# How to use decode in group?

Tags: plsql

I wrote the query as follows,

```
 select col1,
     col2,
     col3,
     col4,
     sum (col8) from my_table
     GROUP BY col1,
     col2,
     col3,
     col4,
     DECODE (  Sys_Context ('CMIC', 'P_GROUP_LEVEL3'), GROUP5,  jbbd_group_code_5,  GROUP4,  jbbd_group_code_4, GROUP3,  jbbd_group_code_3, GROUP2,  jbbd_group_code_2, GROUP1,  jbbd_group_code_1,
     jbbd_group_code_5),
     DECODE (  Sys_Context ('CMIC', 'P_GROUP_LEVEL2'), GROUP5,  jbbd_group_code_5,  GROUP4,  jbbd_group_code_4, GROUP3,  jbbd_group_code_3, GROUP2,  jbbd_group_code_2, GROUP1,  jbbd_group_code_1,
     jbbd_group_code_3),
     DECODE (  Sys_Context ('CMIC', 'P_GROUP_LEVEL1'), GROUP5,  jbbd_group_code_5,  GROUP4,  jbbd_group_code_4, GROUP3,  jbbd_group_code_3, GROUP2,  jbbd_group_code_2, GROUP1,  jbbd_group_code_1,
     jbbd_group_code_2);
```

Main purpose of this query is to dynamically assign group, by based on context parameter value. But it is giving me the error shown below.

> ORA-00904: "GROUP1": invalid identifier
>
> 904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>        *Cause:
>        *Action:
>        _Error at Line: 85 Column: 175

What could be the cause of this problem and how could it be resolved?

Comment: I understand that code you posted is just an example. However, it looks OK. Oracle says that error is at line 85, column 175. That is some *large* piece of code. As you didn't post it and regarding the fact that it is difficult to debug code you can't see, I'm afraid you'll have to investigate it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Without the tables ect behind this I cant test it to see if there are other issues but the Sys_Context call will return a string, at the moment you are trying to compare it with an object GROUP1 ect.

For the decode to compare as a string you need to surround each one with single quotes as per the below.

```
select col1,
     col2,
     col3,
     col4,
     sum (col8) from my_table
     GROUP BY col1,
     col2,
     col3,
     col4,
     DECODE (  Sys_Context ('CMIC', 'P_GROUP_LEVEL3'), 'GROUP5',  jbbd_group_code_5,  'GROUP4',  jbbd_group_code_4, 'GROUP3',  jbbd_group_code_3, 'GROUP2',  jbbd_group_code_2, 'GROUP1',  jbbd_group_code_1,
     jbbd_group_code_5),
     DECODE (  Sys_Context ('CMIC', 'P_GROUP_LEVEL2'), 'GROUP5',  jbbd_group_code_5,  'GROUP4',  jbbd_group_code_4, 'GROUP3',  jbbd_group_code_3, 'GROUP2',  jbbd_group_code_2, 'GROUP1',  jbbd_group_code_1,
     jbbd_group_code_3),
     DECODE (  Sys_Context ('CMIC', 'P_GROUP_LEVEL1'), 'GROUP5',  jbbd_group_code_5,  'GROUP4',  jbbd_group_code_4, 'GROUP3',  jbbd_group_code_3, 'GROUP2',  jbbd_group_code_2, 'GROUP1',  jbbd_group_code_1,
     jbbd_group_code_2);
```